# Asp.Core Depenency Injection Session Null

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a Asp.Core project with dependency injection. The problem is that when I get an instance of a CustomerService my `session` is `null`. But I pass it through with dependency injection.

My Controller looks like this:

```
private ISessionService _sessionService;
private IContainer _container;

public AuthController(ISessionService sessionService, IContainer container) {
    _container = container;
    _sessionService = sessionService;

    // here my session is NOT NULL
    string userName = _sessionService.Username;
}

public IActionResult Index() {
    // here I have some code so the line below is not always needeed and   therefore not injected in the constructor
    IUserService userService = _container.GetInstance<IUserService>();

    // here my session is NULL
    string name = userService.GetUserName();
}

public class UserService : IUserService {

    private ISessionService _sessionService;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserService(ISessionService sessionSerivce, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        _sessionService = sessionSerivce;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetUserName() {
        return _sessionService.User.Name;
    }
}
```

my StartUp.cs where I'm using `StructureMap`

```
Container container = new Container(expr => {
    expr.For<IHttpContextAccessor>().Use<HttpContextAccessor>();
    expr.For<ISessionService>().Use<SessionService>();
    expr.For<IUserService>().Use<UserService>();
});
```

So why is my session null when I instantiate a UserService object when using the container class ?

**UPDATE**

I know now that the Session object is null because the `life cycle` of a MVC page. In my BaseController class I created a method named `InitContainer` like this:

```
public void InitContainer(Type typeOfInterface, Type typeOfClass) {
    Configure(expr =>
        For(typeOfInterface).Use(typeOfClass)                
            .Ctor<ISessionService>().Is(_sessionService)
            .Ctor<IHttpContextAccessor>().Is(_httpContextAccessor)
        );
    }
}
```

When I want to use an instance of a service than I do this in my Controller method:

```
public IActionResult Test() {
        InitContainer(typeof(ICustomerService), typeof(CustomerService));
        ICustomerService customerService = _container.GetInstance<ICustomerService>();
}
```

I don't know if it's ugly or the right way to do this, but it works for me now.
Has someone a better way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to inject an instance of `IContainer` into your controller. Can you also provide us with your `Startup.cs` file please?

Comment: Since your controller already has an instance of `_sessionService ` when it is created, why not just use `_sessionService.Username` inside of the `Index()` method?